# Extracting string with regex stored in hash

Tags: regex, perl, hash

I'm trying to parse out specific values from a text file, and output those to a different file.

I'm using regular expressions stored in a hash (matched up with their descriptive name) to search through a string (scalar), and then storing the discovered values in an array, which is then written out to a file.

I've got everything working, except for the searching/extracting part.
(I've only just learned Perl in the past couple days, so I wouldn't be surprised if I was making some really simple mistakes.)

```
$inputstring = 'Lorem ipsum dolor Date: 20110131 quis semper egestas.';

%myregexhash = ( Date => '/([12][09][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-2][0-9][0-9])/' );

@foundvaluesarray=();

while ( ($thefieldname, $theregex) = each (%myregexhash))
{
    if ($inputstring =~ $theregex) 
    {
        push(@foundvaluesarray, "$thefieldname: $&\n");
        $inputstring = $';
    }
}

print "@foundvaluesarray";
```

The array fills up with the field names ("Date:"), but not the values I'm looking for ("20110131").

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make one small change:

```
%myregexhash = ( Date => qr/([12][09][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-2][0-9][0-9])/ );
```

Note the use of [`qr//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators), which compiles a regex.

You're new, so I'd recommend a few other changes.

Any non-trivial program should begin with the following front matter:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
```

The `strict` pragma has nice benefits such as catching misspelled variable names at compile time and checking your use of references. The `warnings` pragma turns on extra warning diagnostics that can alert you to questionable cases in your code.

Now must predeclare:

```
my $inputstring = 'Lorem ipsum dolor Date: 20110131 quis semper egestas.';

my %myregexhash = ( Date => qr/([12][09][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-2][0-9][0-9])/ );

my @foundvaluesarray=();
```

The `= ()` is implied in an array or hash declaration, so you don't see it in idiomatic Perl.

You don't want to use `$&` if you can help it because it [slows down your entire program](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups).

> **WARNING:** Once Perl sees that you need one of `$&`, `` $` ``, or `$'` anywhere in the program, it has to provide them for every pattern match. This may substantially slow your program. Perl uses the same mechanism to produce `$1`, `$2`, etc., so you also pay a price for each pattern that contains capturing parentheses. (To avoid this cost while retaining the grouping behaviour, use the extended regular expression `(?: ... )` instead.) But if you never use `$&`, `` $` `` or `$'`, then patterns without capturing parentheses will not be penalized. So avoid `$&`, `$'` , and `` $` `` if you can, but if you can't (and some algorithms really appreciate them), once you've used them once, use them at will, because you've already paid the price. As of 5.005, `$&` is not so costly as the other two.

Because you surrounded your pattern with parentheses, the substring that matched is captured in `$1`, so grab it from there.

Also, the way you chopped off the front of `$inputstring` is much more naturally expressed in Perl with `s///`.

```
while (my ($thefieldname, $theregex) = each (%myregexhash))
{
    if ($inputstring =~ s/$theregex//) 
    {
        push(@foundvaluesarray, "$thefieldname: $1\n");
    }
}

print "@foundvaluesarray";
```

Output:

```
Date: 20110131
```

Comment: Wow -- that totally fixed it! Thanks so much!!
Great other tips too; I've fixed it all, and it's working great. :)

Comment: Hmm, it should have worked without qr.  Oh, I see, the / don't belong in the string.